# Multiple YouTube players embedded in mobile site freeze if sound is on and device orientation changes

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I've got a mobile website with 3 youtube playlists made using the api like so:

```
yellowplayer = new YT.Player('first', {
    videoId: 'PLzzXVNvzpHwrvyHwGLIHiU2Z1Lii6sVOz',
    playerVars: { 
        'autoplay':1,
        'controls': 0, 
        'loop':1,
        'list':'PLzzXVNvzpHwrvyHwGLIHiU2Z1Lii6sVOz',
        'playsinline':1,
        'mute':1,
        'start':11
    }       
}) 

blueplayer = new YT.Player('second', {
    videoId: 'PLzzXVNvzpHwoT1D9Cd4dnfZwpGIg1u4EI',
    playerVars: { 
        'autoplay': 1, 
        'controls': 0, 
        'loop':1,
        'list':'PLzzXVNvzpHwoT1D9Cd4dnfZwpGIg1u4EI',
        'playsinline':1,
        'mute':1,
        'start':11
    }
})

redplayer = new YT.Player('third', {
    videoId: 'PLzzXVNvzpHwqZaKYqdmPTOw808fmXvyPc',
    playerVars: { 
        'autoplay': 1, 
        'controls': 0, 
        'loop':1,
        'list':'PLzzXVNvzpHwqZaKYqdmPTOw808fmXvyPc',
        'playsinline':1,
        'mute':1,
        'start':11
    }
})
```

everything works while the players are muted. i can change the orientation of the device all i want and everything plays fine.

i am unmuting the videos through a button click.  this also works fine until the device is rotated.

once the orientation changes one or two of the videos pause.  when i try checking for the paused player state and restarting the video, it immediately pauses again. if i only unmute one of the videos instead of all 3 everything works.

the videos play just fine as long as there is no change in orientation OR no more than one video's sound.

???